# Change Lookup(master) table rows to "readonly" when already in use

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

We have many lookup tables in the system and if it's already referred by some other tables, we shouldn't be allowed to update or delete the look-up table "value" column. eg: EnrollStatusName in below table.

Eg:

Lookup table: EnrollStatus

| ID | EnrollStatusName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pending |
| 2 | Approved |
| 3 | Rejected |

Other table: UserRegistration

| URID | EnrollStatusID(FK) |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 |
| 12 | 1 |
| 13 | 2 |

In this now I can edit Lookup table row 3 since it's not referring anywhere.

The solution which comes to my mind is to add a read-only column to look up the table and whenever there is a DML to the UserRegistration table, update the read-only column to true. Is there any other best approach to this? It can be either handling in application code or in SQL hence I'm tagging c# also to know the possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete is easy; just establish a foreign key relationship to some other table, and don't cascade or setnull. It's no longer possible to delete the in-use row because it has dependent rows in other tables

Update is perhaps trickier. You can use the same mechanism and I think it's neatest, instead of doing the update as an update, do it as a delete and insert - if the row is in use the foreign key will prevent the delete..

Belayer pointed out in the comments that you can use UPDATE also; you'll have to include the PK column in the list of columns you set and you can't set it to the same value it already is, nor to a value that is already in use. You'll probably need a strategy like two updates in a row if you want to have a controlled list of IDs

```
UPDATE EnrollStatus SET id=-id, EnrollStatusName='whatever' WHERE id=3
UPDATE EnrollStatus SET id=-id WHERE id=-3
```

A strategy of flipping it negative then back positive will work out only if it's not in use. If it is used then it will error out on the first statement.

If you don't care that your PKs end up a mix of positives and negatives (and you shouldn't, but people do seem to care more than they should about what values PKs have) you can forego the second update; you can always insert new values as positive incrementing and flipflop them while they're being edited before being brought into use..

Comment: @CaiusJard. There is no need  for delete/insert. Update is no trickier than delete. A FK responds to UPDATE with exactly the same error as it does with DELETE provided *on update cascade* or *on update set null* is not specified.

Comment: You're right; I was working from an assumption that this table's pk is some carefully curated list of values and delete/insert is an easy way to maintain it. I've edited the answer

Comment: @Belayer, You are right when we update the PK field. we are not updating the PK field but the value field which I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: @CaiusJard, an update with a negative is not recommended and we should not be modifying the PK column.

Comment: Those rules sound very arbitrary